# Nef line bundles on threefolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective threefold over the space of complex numbers. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$ such that  $D_1,D_2\in |L|$ are linearly equivalent disjoint divisors.

Then is it true that $L^2=L^3=0$? Is it possible to have another line bundle $H$ such that $L^2.H>0$?

This seems like a silly question to me. But I am learning about nef line bundles and playing around with some examples to get a feel for it. Any intuition/help will be very useful.

Comment: Yes, $L^2=0$ (and thus) $L^3=0$.

Comment: What about the next question? Can we have another line bundle with $L.L.H>0$? This is not possible since $L^2$ is zero right

Comment: Once $L^2=0$, you cannot have $L^2\cdot H>0$ for any $H$.